# Tablayout is showing borders around tabs in android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-tablayout

I upgraded few things in my project i.e from `targetSdkVersion 27` to `targetSdkVersion 28`, upgraded gradle

Everything was working fine before but after update my tabLayout is showing borders around tab as showing in picture below. How can I resolve this issue. I searched for this issue but unable to see any question related to it

[image]

just in case if someone wants to see my tablayout xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/available_bundle_details_tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_23sdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_23sdp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lyt_available_bundle_detail_header"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selection_state"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#506694"
            app:tabTextColor="#96506694"
            />
```

Here is the `tab_selection_state` that I am using as `tabBackground`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- UNSELECTED TAB STATE -->
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false">
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <!-- Bottom indicator color for the UNSELECTED tab state -->
            <item android:top="-5dp" android:left="-5dp" android:right="-5dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <stroke android:color="#96506694" android:width="1dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <!-- SELECTED TAB STATE -->
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <!-- Bottom indicator color for the SELECTED tab state -->
            <item android:top="-5dp" android:left="-5dp" android:right="-5dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <stroke android:color="#506694" android:width="2dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: maybe margin, shadow, or border..., various reasons.

Comment: Please post your drawable/tab_selection_state (and the drawables referred from there). Since they define what your tab looks like, I suppose the borders must come from somewhere in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The borders come from your custom drawables, which draw a rectangle around each tab. Its hard to say, why this only happens with targetSDK=28, but you can definitely fix it by revisiting your custom drawables.

Try to first remove the rectangle (or set color to transparent) and then try to bring it back step by step to figure out, what exactly causes the problem.